# How to get time when all elements rendered and show it in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

I have a big list with elements, that generates from server response data. The problem is that when data updates it automatically renders elements that bounded to this data and it makes UI blocked.

The question is, how can I catch that moment when all elements were rendered and show that list without blocking UI?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the data is updated then the rendering is done sync. If you schedule your "after-updated" code using `this.async(function () { ....})` (after the data was updated) your code executed after the rendering is done (and previously scheduled tasks are processed).